# Expression for Comparing Dates

Tags: date, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

I have a dataset called "PastDates" and I want to compare that date to today's date minus 2 weeks. So it would be something along the lines of:

```
Fields!PastDates.Value > Today() - 14 days
```

I need help putting that into an expression, specifically the second part (Today() - 14 days)

Answer (score 1):

The date functions are all Visual Basic based, so if you look at date examples in VB, you should be able to do pretty much the same thing

`=Fields!PastDates.Value > (DateAdd(DateInterval.Day, -14, Today()))`